# What does lemon taste like?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

What Lemon tastes like? salty? or lemoney?

Edit:

Thanks for the answers guys, I know sour is one of the basic tastes but I thought gooseberry tastes sour. If Lemon tastes sour then what does gooseberry taste like?

In our native language Telugu, both has different tastes and meanings.

Comment: Lemons are sour, as others have said, but of course lemons are lemony, too. However, I'd be more likely to use _lemony_ when describing something other than a lemon (such as a lemon meringue pie, for example).

Comment: They both are sour in the same way that a chocolate bar and a candy cane are both sweet, but they have different accompanying flavors.

Comment: I agree with @Jim – it's pretty hard to ascribe just one adjective to describe a taste; each adjective adds to the description. Just think about all the ways reviewers describe a good [wine](http://buyingguide.winemag.com/editors/rv), for example.

Comment: Do you have vinegar? It is mildly sour. Gooseberries are not sour, they are fruity-sweet. Sometimes unripe berries are sour. Unripe apples are sour. If you have rhubarb, you're all set.

Comment: Isn't vinegar more *sharp* than *sour*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lemons taste [*sour*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sour).

> **sour** (*comparative* **sourer**, *superlative* **sourest**)
>   1. Having an [acidic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/acid), [sharp](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sharp) or [tangy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tangy) taste.
>   *Lemons have a sour taste.*

Answer (score 4):

A **sour** taste, such as that of a lemon, has the unique property of activating one's salivary glands on contact. Salty, bitter, and sweet things do not cause this experience.

This is such a remarkable occurrence with sour tasting foods that if you simply concentrate on imagining the taste of lemons or limes (if you are familiar with them), you will often get a sudden increase in the flow of saliva. (We sometimes use this occurrence in medicine as a test of salivary gland function!)

Comment: Apparently, this salivation thing is also true of [***umami***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umami#Properties_of_umami_taste): “Umami has a mild but lasting aftertaste that is difficult to describe. It induces salivation and a sensation of furriness on the tongue, stimulating the throat, the roof and the back of the mouth.”

Comment: You know, I almost considered it did occur with umami, then decided it didn't. Thanks for the correction. I will pay more attention in Japanese restaurants from now on. :-)